# Upgrade Linux in VMware

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I use Ubuntu in virtual machine. My current version of Ubuntu is 14.04, I want to upgrade it to the latest version which is 16.04.

I opened Software Updater, it checked for update and said:

> The software on this computer is up to date, however Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS is now available.

So I clicked the upgrade button and entered my password.

BUT it failed, nothing happened.

I repeated a couple of times, still the same result.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade from one version to another, first you need to prepare your system, I mean, updating and upgrading. If not, you wont be able to upgrade.

**System preparation**

Just in case repositories are disabled (if they are, you wont be able to update), go to

```
Main Menu: System > Administration > Software Sources.
```

It will display you a window, that must look like this one.

[image]

Tick all of em like in the pic!

Now we are going to update the system.
Be sure you have conection to internet, and open a terminal prompt (`ctl + alt + T`). Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once updating had finished, let's upgrade the system. In the same terminal prompt run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Wait until the prompt finishes.

**Upgrading to 16.04**

If all of this worked without erros, you must be able to upgrade to 16.04. In the same terminal prompt, just run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Now you can sit and relax, the upgrade will take some time.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more , "preparing the system, updating and upgrading" ? I am new to linux. Also , I thought software updater do the job?

Comment: I've edited the answer, so it will be easier for you to understand. I hope this works ^^
You need to have the repositories enabled in order to perform the upgrade :)

Comment: I meant I understood what I need to do. But I want to know what do you mean by preparing the system, what system? What is the difference between update and upgrade? What does update do here?What does upgrade do here? Why after upgrade need to do release upgrade again? can you explain what each command do? I'm sorry for long quest. Thanks so much

Comment: Update checks the new upgrades avaliable , and upgrade installs em. First you need to update the system, so it will refresh the avaliable downloads. If you just upgrade, you wont get the last upgrades, since you havent refresed em with update. Also, the system must be up to date in upgrades to perform the change to 16.04.

Comment: Hi when I am waiting for the upgrade to complete, my internet connection dies in the middle. Now how do i resume this?

Comment: You can run again ´sudo do-release-upgrade´ . Once the upgrade is finished, run ´sudo apt-get autoclean´ and ´sudo apt-get autoremove´. It will remove and delete no necesary packages, so everything that has been downloaded twice while the upgrade, will be deleted.