# Ubuntu Upgrade from 14.04 to a new version

Tags: upgrade

When I turn on my PC, a message comes up asking if I want to upgrade Ubuntu. When I click on yes, it gives this error

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Hey, check this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/807914/upgrade-linux-in-vmware/807922#807922 I've wrote this morning, maybe it can fix your problem.

Comment: What's odd about the error message you got is that you probably already have apt 1.0.1ubuntu2.14 installed so you shouldn't be getting that error message. To prove it run `apt-cache policy apt`